# Please help me make sense of this php debug error (Braintree-WooCommerce extension)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, braintree

Can anyone help me translate this PHP error into English?

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Braintree_Exception_Authentication'
in
/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-gateway-braintree/braintree_php/lib/Braintree/Util.php:59
Stack trace: #0
/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-gateway-braintree/braintree_php/lib/Braintree/Http.php(31):
Braintree_Util::throwStatusCodeException(401) #1
/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-gateway-braintree/braintree_php/lib/Braintree/CreditCard.php(175):
 Braintree_Http::get('/payment_method...') #2
/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-gateway-braintree/classes/class-wc-gateway-braintree.php(334):
Braintree_CreditCard::find('5kbn9') #3
/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/themes/urbin/woocommerce/checkout/review-order.php(259):
WC_Gateway_Braintree->payment_fields() #4
/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce-core-functions.php(617):
include('/opt/bitnami/ap...') #5 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordp
in/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-gateway-braintree/braintree_php/lib/Braintree/Util.phpon
line 59
```

I'm not sure how best to attack it. This was from a clean install of the [WooCommerce Braintree Payment Gateway](http://www.woothemes.com/products/braintree/) plugin

Comment: i think the BrainTree / SkyVerge team are the ones to know this first.. Did you contact them?

Comment: I work at SkyVerge - just replied to your ticket and we should be able to get you sorted out if you provide us some additional info. thanks! -Max

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sub>I work at Braintree. If you want more detailed help than we can give on Stack Overflow, please get in touch with [our support team](https://www.braintreepayments.com/support).</sub>

I'm not familiar with the internals of  SkyVerge's WooCommerce plugin, but a [`Braintree_Exception_Authentication` generally means a problem with your API keys](https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/php/general/exceptions#authentication_error):

> ## Authentication Error
>
> You’ll receive an authentication exception if your API keys are incorrect. If getting this exception when first integrating, double-check that you didn’t accidentally try to use your sandbox keys in production or vice versa.

Our [Support Center describes where to find your API Keys in production](https://support.braintreepayments.com/customer/portal/articles/787377-api-keys):

> ## API Keys
>
> Your API keys and merchant ID are the credentials that you'll use to connect to the Braintree API. You can locate these parameters by the following steps:
>
> - Login to the Control Panel: https://www.braintreegateway.com/login.
> - Navigate to the drop-down menu in the top right by hovering over your account name and click My User
> - Click the orange link titled "API Keys"
> - If no API keys appear, click the "Generate New" button
> - Click "View" under the Private Key column.
>
> The values will appear on the resulting page. You'll also have the option to copy the API configuration code directly to your clipboard by selecting a language and clicking "Copy".

If you're looking for your API keys in sandbox, they're on the screen as soon as you log in.

Comment: Thank you, agf! I contacted your support line and they were able to help me work out the issues.

For anyone else that experiences this issue: The problem was that although I had entered the API keys correctly, the plugin's Gateway Settings were still configured to post to Sandbox instead of Production. I did not realize that Sandbox needed its own set up API keys, unique from the production keys.